# How to add to a variable value for every loop is done? (in C++. Read more..Complicated Que)

Tags: c++

I have a 'For Loop' that has variable in it as a "itemPrice", and it is a variable that it is value received by input from the user("cin >> itemPrice;" the code is below too). the variable outside the 'For Loop' called 'totalPrice' which I want it every time a price is entered from 'itemPrice' and adds it to the previous price, and so on until user is finished adding. Does anybody know how to do it? My brain is frying because I can't figure out how to do it.

here is my block of code i tried to do:

```
for(itemNumber = 0; itemNumber < 30; itemNumber++){
   cout <<"Please input item price of item of #:"<< itemNumber << endl;
   cout <<"(if You are finished enter 00.)"
   cin >> itemPrice;

   if(itemPrice == 00)
   {
     break;
   }
}

totalPrice //Here I want to add it to this variable for every previous value
           //of 'itemPrice' that entered adds it to the previouse value, and
           //so on.
```

Comment: it is not homework...It is a practice, and idea came to me. I needed to make it. @SamVarshavchik

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Is this relevant somehow? This question is terrible.

Comment: @HellzYeahh Tried something like `total += itemPrice`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  if you put it inside loop, it gives me negative long number. if outside, it does't display or cout.

Comment: @HellzYeahh Initialize all your variables correctly. I really don't get what's your problem. See the code from my answer.

Comment: `cin >> itemPrice` doesn't distinguish between `00` and `0` - both of them = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you describe is very simple. I don't get what's not clear for you how to solve that:

```
double itemPrice = 0.0;
double totalPrice = 0.0; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
for(itemNumber = 0; itemNumber < 30; itemNumber++){
   cout <<"Please input item price of item of #:"<< itemNumber << endl;
   cout <<"(if You are finished enter 00.)"
   cin >> itemPrice;

   if(itemPrice == 00) // <<<< This might be problematic, but not for an input of 0
   {
     break;
   }
   totalPrice += itemPrice; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}

std::cout << "Total: " << totalPrice << std::endl;
```

Comment: It worked! Holycrap mate! you need a award or something, I wish i can give you something in return. :D you the best.

Comment: @HellzYeahh _"you the best"_ Certainly not. I'm just another coffee junkie.

Comment: I don't care. You just made a person day, and motivated me to be smart like you, I look up to people like you. You did something only noobs like me can really appreciate. I googled question, and tried research haven't found an answer, also it is not duplicate question. Pal you are a hero if somebody haven't told you that. Keep it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can us total price inside for loop and set the value as

```
totalprice=itemprice+totalprice;
```

and then you can print the final value of total price out of for loop

Answer (score 1):

```
    int totalPrice = 0;
 for(itemNumber = 0; itemNumber < 30; itemNumber++){
    cout <<"Please input item price of item of #:"<< itemNumber << endl;
    cout <<"(if You are finished enter 00.)"
    cin >> itemPrice;
    totalPrice+=itemPrice;
    if(itemPrice == 00)
    {
      break;
    }
 }

cout<<totalPrice;
```